# SwiftUI Cell Background colour - don't fill full cell

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking to see if its possible to change the background colour of a cell, but fill it based on a percentage

I'm creating the cell in a List {}

```swift
    let gradient = LinearGradient(colors: [.green, .white], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)

    List {
        Section(header: Text("Total")) {
            Text("Total Obtained: \(totalObtained) - \(totalComplete)%")
                    .listRowBackground(gradient)
        }
    }
```

totalComplete has the percentage variable

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want the fill to look? Is the gradient supposed to reflect the percentage? Or should the cell by filled vertically by totalComplete? And what is the role of totalObtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking how you want the fill to look and might change my answer when you reply

In the meantime, if you were just using the gradient to give a rough illustration of how the partial fill should look, then here is an attempt to show how it could be implemented. It uses a `GeometryReader` to deliver the width of the cell and sets the background to a fraction of this width. Adjust the slider to see it work.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    private let targetObtained = 123456.0
    @State private var totalComplete = 50.0
    private var totalObtained: Double {
        targetObtained * totalComplete / 100.0
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Total")) {
                    Text("Total Obtained: \(totalObtained) - \(totalComplete)%")
                        .listRowBackground(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.green
                                    .frame(width: (totalComplete / 100.0) * proxy.size.width)
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 150)
            Slider(
                value: $totalComplete,
                in: 0...100
            )
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

[image: A table with four rows. Each row initially says "Stopped: 0%". I tap each row and it changes to "Running: 0%". The percentage increases by 10 every 1/6th of a second until the row reads "Running: 100%". As the percentage of a row increases, the background of the row changes from white to green, filling in from left to right, like a horizontal bar graph.]

You can do this by using a different initializer to set up your gradient.

Set up the gradient with four stops like this, where `f` is the fraction complete, from 0 to 1:

[image: the gradient described in the text below]

The four stops are as follows:

| Stop index | Location | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | `.green` |
| 1 | `f` | `.green` |
| 2 | `f` | `.white` |
| 3 | 1 | `.white` |

Notice that stops 1 and 2 are at the same location, so the color change is instantaneous at that location and doesn't show a visible gradient.

Here's the code for the row view in my animation:

```
struct RowView: View {
    @State var progress: CGFloat = 0
    @State var running = false

    private func myGradient() -> some View {
        LinearGradient(
            stops: [
                .init(color: .green, location: 0),
                .init(color: .green, location: progress),
                .init(color: .white, location: progress),
                .init(color: .white, location: 1),
            ],
            startPoint: .leading,
            endPoint: .trailing
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(running ? "Running" : "Stopped"): \(progress, format: .percent)")
            Spacer()
        }
        .listRowBackground(myGradient())
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            running.toggle()
        }
        .task {
            while !Task.isCancelled {
                if running && progress < 1 {
                    progress = min(progress + 0.1, 1)
                }
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.0 / 6))
            }
        }
    }
}
```